# suppress namespace prefixes on nsxmlparser

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser, xml-parsing

my xml data has nodes in this format . I want to suppress the prefixes, that is when i pull the element name in nsxmlparser's delegate method it should not return as "yyy" and not as "xxx:yyy"

I tries to do this

```
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
[parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
```

this code did not had any effect. what has to be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:YES];
[parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
```

i got it . . should change the 2nd line to 
YES.

Answer (score 0):

In your

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
```

you can probably use

```
[attributeDict objectForKey:@"xx"]; to get yyy
```